# CreationTimePattern is not setting correct creation date with Azure Data Explorer LightIngest tool

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I'm using the Azure Data Explorer command line utility LightIngest to bulk load historical data from an azure blobstore container.  The data is being loaded but the creation time is not being set on the extent.  Instead of using the date extracted by the creationTimePattern its using the current date.  Here is a file I'm trying to load from the blobstore container:

`https://prj.blob.core.windows.net/historical-feb-2019/2019-02-01T00-13-00.tsv.gz`

And am using the following for the creationTimePattern:

`-creationTimePattern:"'*'YYYY-MM-dd'*.tsv.gz'"`

I cannot change the file name/structure and there are timestamps in every file name

Comment: does this work? `-creationTimePattern:"'/'yyyy-MM-dd'T'"`

Comment: That worked, the right date is set

Answer (score 0):

For people who may come across something similar, using the `-listonly` command line parameter will show whether the pattern is derived correctly from your file/blob name:

```
ListAndFilterFiles: enumerating files under 'C:\Temp'
==> Size (bytes): '1474722', CreationTime: '2023-05-30T00:00:00', Path: 'C:\Temp\input30-05-2023.json.gz'

*** NO DATA WAS INGESTED IN THIS RUN ***

    Done. Time elapsed: 00:00:00.0721914
    Items discovered: [      2], filtered: [      1], accepted: [      1]
```

When there is no pattern match, it will show

```
ListAndFilterFiles: enumerating files under 'C:\Temp'
==> Size (bytes): '1474722', Path: 'C:\Temp\input30-05-2023.json.gz'
```